# "Error incorrect length (0), expecting: 110" when building shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Newbie need some help on first Shiny App. 
I want to filter several countrys and draw an simple line chart depend on that. But I'm getting error: "Error in eval: incorrect length (0), expecting: 110 Stack trace (innermost first)"

Here is code. Thanks for your help :)

## ui.r

```
> shinyUI(fluidPage(   
> titlePanel("Die Selbstmordraten einiger OECD-Staaten"),
>      sidebarLayout(
>     sidebarPanel(         
>     checkboxGroupInput("land", "Land auswählen", choices = c ("Deutschland", "Griechenland", "Ungarn", "Litauen","Luxemburg"))
>     ),
>     mainPanel(
>       plotOutput("plot")
>     ))))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  filter1<-reactive({
    data%>%
      filter(Land == input$landInput)

  })  

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(filter(), aes(Jahr, Rate, group=Land, colour=Land))+
    geom_line(size=.5)+geom_point()+
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())

    })
})
```

Comment: 1) you havent `landInput` only `land`  2) may be you need `%in%` instead of `==`  3) you havent reactive `filter()` only `filter1()`

Comment: Works fine! Thank you, dude :)

Answer (score 2):

For me the error was

```
incorrect length (0), expecting: 6132
```

I found that it was due to mismatch between the input variable and filter name. The input variables that I used was all in small case but in the dplyr filter, the first letter was in caps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  filter1<-reactive({
    req(input$landInput, data)

    data%>%
      filter(Land == input$landInput)

  })  

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    req(filter())

    ggplot(filter(), aes(Jahr, Rate, group=Land, colour=Land))+
    geom_line(size=.5)+geom_point()+
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())

    })
})
```

Comment: I think you have a small typo in your code. You reference `filter()` in `renderPlot()` and I think you want to reference your reactive function `filter1()` in `req()` and `ggplot()`