# Reactive class error when creating a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following dataset:

```
Type <- c("Choice 1", "Choice 1", "Choice 1", "Choice 1", "Choice 1", 
  "Choice 1")
Date <- c("02-02-2016", "02-03-2016", "02-04-2016", "02-05-2016", 
  "02-06-2016", "02-07-2016")
Sentiment <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(Type, Date, Sentiment)
```

Right now I am building a shiny app that allows you to filter a date range and select a type. It should then should you a histogram of all the sentiment values in the subset.

Therefore I created the following shiny code

```
df <- read.csv2("sample.csv", stringAsFactors = F)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  #Sliders for the first panel
  tabPanel( "Tab 1",sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                     start = "2015-01-01",
                     end   = "2015-12-31"),
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"),
        choices = list("Choice 1" = 1,"Choice 2" = 2,"Choice 3" = 3),
        selected = 1)),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("coolplot"))),

  #Sliders for the second panel
  tabPanel("Tab 2", mainPanel("the results of tab2"))
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$select)) {
      return(NULL) }
    df %>% filter(Date >= input$dateRangeInput[1],
             Date <= input$dateRangeInput[2],
             Type == input$select)
  })

  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(Sentiment)) +  geom_histogram()
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However when I run I get the following error:

```
incorrect length (0), expecting: 10
```

Any thoughts on what I should do to avoid this error?

Comment: `ggplot(filtered, aes(Sentiment))` should be `ggplot(filtered(), aes(Sentiment))`, because `filtered` is a **function** returning something.

Comment: Many thanks nrussell! It got this bug out of the way. Only now I run into the following error... (see edit). Any thoughts?

Comment: `gincorrect length (0), expecting: 10` was the *complete* error message?

Comment: My apologies, I meant: incorrect length (0), expecting: 10

Comment: Looks like a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522810/error-incorrect-length-0-expecting-110-when-building-shiny-app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a typical Shiny initialization error. Every reactive gets invoked once at the beginning of execution before any inputs are defined, so they are all NULL at this point and this leads to all kinds of different errors - and hard to diagnose if you are not aware of the problem.

Fairly recently an addition to Shiny (the `req` function) has been made to make this easier to work around. Simply add a:

```
  req(input$dateRangeInput);
```

as the first line in your in your `filter` reactive code.

And remember to do this any time you have a reactive. In fact you also need it anywhere else you are using `input$something` constructs directly, like in `observe` or in `output` code blocks where you use the `input$something` directly.

You will need Shiny version 0.13.0 or better for this. If you have an older version of Shiny you have to guard your code with statements of the form:

```
if (!is.null(input$something)){
   #your code that needs input$something
}
```